# Installing IlyaKipnis Packages from Github in R

Tags: r, github, package

I am trying to use devtools in R to install the repo "IKTrading" from github. I am getting the ERROR: COMMAND FAILED. I have tried using different syntax including install_github("IlyaKipnis/IKTrading") however i recieve the same error.

```
require(devtools)
install_github(repo="IKTrading", username="IlyaKipnis")



Installing github repo IKTrading/master from IlyaKipnis
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/IlyaKipnis/IKTrading/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyqBSv3/master.zip
Installing IKTrading
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyqBSv3\devtools1bf4ff63b09\IKTrading-master"  \
  --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'IKTrading' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:202: warning: overriding recipe for target `.m.o'
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:195: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `.m.o'
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-             3.1.1/library/xts/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/inline/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/TTR/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/quantmod/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/stats/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -  mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG    -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-         3.1.1/library/xts/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program    Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/inline/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/TTR/include" -   I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/quantmod/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-   3.1.1/library/stats/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -     mtune=core2 -c RcppFuns.cpp -o RcppFuns.o
  process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename IKTrading.dll .dll, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename IKTrading.dll .dll, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename IKTrading.dll .dll, ...) failed.
"zRcppExports.o RcppFuns.o" was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [IKTrading.dll] Error 255
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-  31~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)'     SHLIB="IKTrading.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o RcppFuns.o"' had status 2
 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'IKTrading'
 * removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/IKTrading'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: Do you have RTools installed

Comment: The package author might respond to a you [opening up an issue](https://github.com/IlyaKipnis/IKTrading/issues)

Comment: @treydog999 Did you solve the issue? Have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to install RTools first and then
packages 'stringi' and 'roxygen2'.  For some reason IKTrading does not download them automatically. Also 'roxygen2' installation will give error if 'stringi' is not installed first.